# Question regarding net available work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work

I am trying to get through this question from Callen's thermodynamics, and yet I had no luck. Precisely I am having a problem finding out what exactly is the thing that question wants:
[image]

- How can I show "that the system does work on the atmosphere?", isn't it clear that when the volume of system containing the system and the atmosphere changes, work is being done?
- What excatly is the Availability?
- In the case of (b), what has the chemical reaction got to do with Availability? is it because the temperature changes?

Thanks in advance for complete or partial solutions to the problem.

Comment: Hello, One. Welcome to PSE.
Some food for thought: when you try to lift a piston, must we overcome atmosphere alone? (;

Comment: @daydreamer Not if its a massless piston or a piston of negligible mass. I suspect that is the assumption being made in 4.5-20